# How best to serialize a list of entities in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the following method to serialize a list of classes to disk:

```
private static void Serialize(List<CcmAlarmUalUsl> entityList)
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("CcmAlarmUalUsl.dat", FileMode.Create))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            bin.Serialize(stream, entityList);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
    }
}
```

The entity class I want to serialize looks like this:

```
public class CcmAlarmUalUsl
{
    public string SubId { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime TimeOfAlarm { get; set; }

    public int AlarmType { get; set; }
}
```

Is my Serialize class the best way to serialize the list of entities to disk? This does not need to be human readable. It is to be used strictly by the application, as a storage means for an internal cache. No database storage is necessary.

I'm also a bit concerned about when it comes time to modify the structure of CcmAlarmUalUsl. I could be adding properties to the end of the class. How will this affect existing cached items?

Comment: What's `lizards1`?  Did you mean that to be `entityList`?

Comment: What is your requirement for the serialized data? If your requirement is that the serialized data is human readable, then no BinaryFormatter is not the best solution, XmlSerializer might be a better option. Your code is also not very clear, you serialize a variable called `lizards1' but the function takes enityList, is it the entityList that you want to serialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer - no.  Your code won't compile (`lizards1`??) and your `CcmAlarmUalUs1` class isn't marked as serializable (run-time error).  Mark your `CcmAlarmUrlUs1` class as serializable, change `lizards1` to `entityList` and it should work and it looks like you're doing things fine.

You're question is kind of vague, though.  By 'best', what are you looking for?  Without knowing that, it's hard to really give a good answer.

Comment: Thank you. 'Lizards1' was a typo. This doesn't need to be human readable. It is strictly as an application storage mechanism to store a cached list of items. This didn't need to get persisted in a database. I've updated my post to include another requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The best way, depends on your application requirements. 
The binary serialization (standart one) is usually cheap in terms of memory used on hard disk, but not very scalable, as one time you refactore your code, you will face *deserialization* problem of previously saved binaries. Which is possible to resolve but I personally don't like that approach and try to avoid it as much as possible.

Consider:

1. XML serialization
2. Json serialization
3. Save object to SQLite DB with some lightweight ORM.
4. *Custom* binary serialization...

There plenty other types out there, but these ones IMHO are more defused ones in these days.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree and add that Json serialzation creates smaller data than XML serialization